# In MS Access query SQL code is changed after closing

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I wrote this SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\file_name.xlsx].[Sheet]
(...)
```

But after closing a quary and opening it again it is:

```
SELECT * 
INTO (Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\file_name.xlsx)) Sheet
(...)
```

What should I do if I want the code to stay the same after closing and opening it again?

I found an information, that both versions should be correct, but the version without square brackets is showing an error in Access

Comment: I don't think can prevent Access modifying SQL statements. Run the SQL in VBA with CurrentDb.Execute.